# Double instructions shown at the thankyou page from wp

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have developed a custom payment method for our marketing team using WordPress. Everything is working fine except for the Thank You page.

When the customer completes the order, the Thank You page renders the instruction content twice. The same issue occurs in the email, and I am unsure why.

Below is the methodology I used to create my custom payment method and the Thank You page:

```
public function __construct()
        {

            $this->id = 'coupon'; 
            $this->icon = ''; 
            $this->has_fields = true;
            $this->title = __('Payment Coupon', 'text-domain'); 

            $this->method_description = __('Custom coupon payment gateway', 'woocommerce'); // payment method description

            // load the settings.
            $this->init_form_fields();
            $this->init_settings();
            
            // Define user set variables.
            $this->title = $this->get_option('title');
            $this->description = $this->get_option('description');
            $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions');
            $this->enabled = $this->get_option('enabled');
            

            add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_coupon', array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );
            add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', array( $this, 'email_instructions' ), 10, 3 );

            // Action hook to save the settings
            if (is_admin()) {
                add_action('woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array($this, 'process_admin_options'));
            }


        }
public function init_form_fields()
        {

            $this->form_fields = array(
                'enabled' => array(
                    'title'       => __('Enable/Disable', 'woocommerce'),
                    'label'       => __('Enable Payment Coupon', 'text-domain'),
                    'type'        => 'checkbox',
                    'description' => __('This enable the Payment Coupon which allow to accept payment through transcash coupon.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'     => 'no',
                    'desc_tip'    => true
                ),
                'title' => array(
                    'title'       => __('Title', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'        => 'safe_text',
                    'description' => __('This controls the title which the user sees during checkout.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'     => __('Coupon transcash', 'woocommerce'),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'description' => array(
                    'title'       => __('Description', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __('Payment method description that the customer will see on your checkout.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'     => __("Payer à l'aide d'un coupon transcash.", 'woocommerce'),
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                ),
                'instructions' => array(
                    'title'       => __('Instructions', 'woocommerce'),
                    'type'        => 'textarea',
                    'description' => __('Instructions qui seront ajoutés à la page de remerciement et dans les e-mails.', 'woocommerce'),
                    'default'     => '',
                    'desc_tip'    => true,
                )
                
                
            );
        }

    /**
     * Output for the order received page.
     *
     * @param int $order_id Order ID.
     */
        public function thankyou_page( $order_id ) {

            if ( $this->instructions ) {
                echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( $this->instructions ) ) ) );
            }
            
        }
```

To resolve the issue, I attempted to identify the location of the problem. I added the following to my code:

before:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_coupon', array( $this, 'thankyou_page' ) );
```

after:

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou_coupon', function() {
    error_log('Action woocommerce_thankyou_coupon déclenchée depuis : ' . debug_backtrace()[0]['file'] . ' à la ligne ' . debug_backtrace()[0]['line']);
});
```

and the result:

```
[28-Sep-2023 07:31:58 UTC] Action woocommerce_thankyou_coupon déclenchée depuis : /home/spri4504/devtc23/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php à la ligne 310
[28-Sep-2023 07:31:58 UTC] Action woocommerce_thankyou_coupon déclenchée depuis : /home/spri4504/devtc23/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php à la ligne 310
```

In the file class-wp-hook.php, the issue is located at line 310, within the elseif statement inside the foreach loop:

```
public function apply_filters( $value, $args ) {
        if ( ! $this->callbacks ) {
            return $value;
        }

        $nesting_level = $this->nesting_level++;

        $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] = array_keys( $this->callbacks );

        $num_args = count( $args );

        do {
            $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] = current( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );

            $priority = $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ];

            foreach ( $this->callbacks[ $priority ] as $the_ ) {
                if ( ! $this->doing_action ) {
                    $args[0] = $value;
                }

                // Avoid the array_slice() if possible.
                if ( 0 == $the_['accepted_args'] ) {
                    $value = call_user_func( $the_['function'] );
                } elseif ( $the_['accepted_args'] >= $num_args ) {
                    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
                } else {
                    $value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], array_slice( $args, 0, (int) $the_['accepted_args'] ) );
                }
            }
        } while ( false !== next( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] ) );

        unset( $this->iterations[ $nesting_level ] );
        unset( $this->current_priority[ $nesting_level ] );

        $this->nesting_level--;

        return $value;
    }
```

To be honest, that hasn't been helpful at all.

Thank you for your time !

---

So i did this :
public function thankyou_page( $order_id ) {

```
        if ( $this->instructions ) {
                echo wp_debug_backtrace_summary();
                echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( $this->instructions ) ) ) );
        }
    }
```

as result i have this ( this appear twice, same as the instruction) :

> require(‘wp-blog-header.php’), require_once(‘wp-includes/template-loader.php’), include(‘/themes/appilo/page.php’),
> get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require(‘/themes/appilo/layouts/content-page-layout.php’),
> appilo_dynamic_template, get_template_part, locate_template, load_template, require(‘/themes/appilo/template-parts/content-page-layouts/content-page-1.php’)
> the_content, apply_filters(‘the_content’), WP_Hook->apply_filters, Elementor\Frontend->apply_builder_in_content, Elementor\Frontend->get_builder_content,
> Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements_with_wrapper, Elementor\Core\Base\Document->print_elements, Elementor\Element_Base->print_element,
> Elementor\Element_Base->print_content, Elementor\Element_Base->print_element, Elementor\Element_Base->print_content,
> Elementor\Element_Base->print_element, Elementor\Widget_Base->print_content, Elementor\Widget_Base->render_content,
> Elementor\Controls_Stack->render_by_mode, Elementor\Widget_Text_Editor->render, Elementor\Widget_Base->parse_text_editor,
> do_shortcode, preg_replace_callback, do_shortcode_tag, WC_Shortcodes::checkout, WC_Shortcodes::shortcode_wrapper, WC_Shortcode_Checkout::output,
> WC_Shortcode_Checkout::order_received, wc_get_template, include(‘/plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php’),
> do_action(‘woocommerce_thankyou_coupon’), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_coupon_Gateway->thankyou_page

https://pastebin.com/nL2yYvXE

I have found the solution i deleted this line at the end of my class :
add_filter('woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_custom_gateway_class');

Comment: The final backtrace will not give you much I believe. Please try to print the whole backtrace to see if they are just the same. If not, this might give us a clue where to look

Comment: And for this you can try to use `wp_debug_backtrace_summary()`

Comment: I appreciate your help and would like to share my results with you, but the character count is too high. Is there another way for me to share the results with you so everyone can see?"

Comment: I think you can use https://pastebin.com/ and insert the link in your question

Comment: Ok i did it  thanks for the tips ! :)

Comment: The provided code is not enough to test and understand the issue you are facing… See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Idk what i can give you more.
 i have try to place a lot of echo like thie 
public function thankyou_page( $order_id ) {
   echo $this->mavaleur . "  en dehors du if"; 
   if ( $this->instructions ) {
     if($this->mavaleur  === '')
     {
      $this->mavaleur = "maNewvaleur";
      echo $this->mavaleur . "mavaleurdansleif";
      echo wp_kses_post( wpautop( wptexturize( wp_kses_post( $this->instructions ) ) ) );
      
     }
     else {
      echo $this->mavaleur . "dans le else";
     }
   }
  }
and i never go on the else, so i believe their is 2 instance of this function